# Add date and text at the last row after a copy paste

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, text, copy-paste

I'm breaking my head here trying to figure it out a way to achieve this in a simples way.

I got working a code that copies a range from a sheet and paste in another at the last row.

```
function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Review");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Log");

  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange(3,2,15,5);
  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,3,15,5);

  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

}
```

The problem is, at the destination sheet, I still have columns A and B empty. By each row in the source (varies from time to time) copied, I need to place at column A todays date and column B the text "Review".

Like: Date (column A) | Revview (column B) | Pasted Data from Source (column C and other)

Do I need to write a completely new code to check for empty or can I implement both solutions into this code?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `The problem is, at the destination sheet, I still have columns A and B empty. By each row in the source (varies from time to time) copied, I need to place at column A todays date and column B the text "Review".`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Sure. Here's a link to the sheet // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18JFUJDleMdgn_CrwgHk3zJhLJV35bkqyGNnrpdstiGk/edit?usp=sharing // I want to get the data from Review and add at the last row to Log starting from column C. However, I need to add also today's date in column A and work type "Review" in column B to each row copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should fill the two cells before your data. It also caters for the setup where you have three areas in the same sheet.

Each `copyInfoXd_button` function will be assigned to your button image.

```
function copyInfo1d_button() {
  copyInfo(2, "B1:B");
}

function copyInfo7d_button() {
  copyInfo(9, "I1:I");
}

function copyInfo30d_button() {
  copyInfo(16, "P1:P");
}


function copyInfo(startingCol, subjectCol)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Review");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Log");
  
  const sourceCols = 4; //actual number of columns to copy, not including the empty column H
  const destCols = 6; //actual number of columns to write to, from DATE to OBS
  
  //find the last row from a colum
  var avals = copySheet.getRange(subjectCol).getValues();
  var lastRow = avals.filter(String).length;
  
  var rowsToCopy = lastRow - 2; //skip the first 2 rows as they are headers

  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange(3,startingCol,rowsToCopy,sourceCols); // row, column, number of rows and number of columns
  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,rowsToCopy,destCols);

  var data = [];

  var sourceValues = source.getValues();

  //construct new data for the destination range
  for (var row in sourceValues) {
      var destRow = [Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'MMMM dd, yyyy'), 'Review'];
      destRow = destRow.concat(sourceValues[row]);
      data.push(destRow);
  }

  destination.setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Charles Han, that solved the problem! Interesting this data.push. Live and learn :)

Comment: Hi Charles, I ran into a problem. It adds date and review only to the last row. But the source range can have up to 15 rows. That means in the paste sheet 14 will be empty! I'm trying to correct that, but it seems that I need some form of counter to data.push this into specific number of rows?

Comment: I get this: Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 6. Tried adding reviewRange = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow(), 1, copySheet.getRange("B4:B19").getValues().length, 2)

Comment: I can't make it work :(

Comment: @JottaKz i have updated my code based on your spreadsheet. Made the copy more dynamic without using 99 or any random numbers.

Comment: Hello again @Charles Han, for some reason, that didn't work. It only copies 2 rows from the source, and there's 3 rows there now. I tried tinker a little bit, don't know where it gets wrong... It looks better than mine though :)

Comment: Try now, I need to skip the first 2 rows as you have them as headers. @JottaKz

Comment: Hello @Charles Han! So... couldn't do it... I have also rows in 7 days. Somehow, they're overlapping. If I click ADD in the 1 day column, it adds the same amount as a total of all columns. I think it's something related to getrange to each block of review

Comment: @JottaKz I have updated the code. I noticed that you have a `Time` column in the destination sheet. I am not sure where you will copy that from. The Observation data is not copied over due to that Time column, but I can fix it if I know where to copy it.

Comment: ! Thank you! I'm seeing it! It's now fully working, I don't know that "const" I'll check some info about it :) It looks much better. I don't understand what you mean by "observation data is not copied"?

Comment: I just saw in the Log sheet the observation data is not copied over. But if it works as what you want, that's good to hear.

Comment: That's true. Didn't realize that. Well, your code had a ```const sourceCols = 4;``` and a ```const destCols = 6; ``` .... what I did is put sourcecols to 5 and destcols to 7. That worked. However, I did as intuition, I don't know what I just did but it's working. Will it brake anything from the sheets?

Comment: That's the right code to change. :)

Comment: Ok... how do I get the lastrow from just one column? I have data on the destination sheet that's on the cell N31, and when I hit the script, the lastrow is taken from 31.

Answer (score 1):

I made it! I'm so proud! Thank you all for the help!

I'm beginning to do stuff like this!

After the Charles answer I looked for a way to add to each row. However, I know the code might not be too elegant, and I couldn't figured it out a way of doing using script itself, so I added a helper cell inside the sheet in H1 and H2.

Here's the solution:

```
function copyInfo24() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Review");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Log");

  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange(4,2,99,5);
  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,3,99,5);

  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  // Sets date at Column A and "Review" at Column B.
  var data = [];
  for(var i =0; i < copySheet.getRange("H1").getValue(); i++) {
    data.push([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'MMMM dd, yyyy'), 'Review']);
  }
  reviewRange = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()-copySheet.getRange("H2").getValue(), 1, copySheet.getRange("H1").getValue(), 2)
  reviewRange.setValues(data); //set the date and 'Review' data

}
```

Comment: Hi @JottaKz just had a quick look at your spreadsheet. Are the numbers in `getRange` constants, for example, `pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,3,99,5)`, is 3 and 99 constant? it looks different from the question you asked and 3 seems to be skipping the first 2 items in your example sheet.

Comment: Hi @CharlesHan, no, actually I couldn't figure it out how to make it variable. The column 3 and up to 5 is constant. The number 99 is not. That's supposed to be the number of rows with data, not empty. The problem is that each day can have different rows. I arbitrarily set 99 because I think it would be enough.

Comment: How do you determine the record should be in Review state? i am just looking for a way to make that a variable or more dynamic.

Comment: It's on the first row of the sheet, review after 1 day, 7 days, 30 days. By using this formula: =IFERROR(query(Log!A2:K,"select C where B = 'Work' and K < "&Planning!$AA$11&" and K is not null and A = date '"&TEXT(IF(Log!AA4="",today(),Log!AA4)-1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1)). // So basically after 1 day, if the column K is less than 80%, I query those subjects to review.